# How to build Angular2 app with external json file using angular-cli in prod mode?

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli, ng2-translate

My Angular2 app is using ng2-translate module and 'en.json' file contains translation. 
This is all working well in dev mode when built end deployed with angular-cli. 
But when built in prod mode, and deployed to WildFly, en.json is not found and translation is not loaded.

How to build app in prod mode, so en.json is packed inside dist directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this issue is related to the `webpack` configuration employed by `angular-cli`. In the current state the `ng build` command keeps content of `src/assets` directory in the `dist` directory.

So you can put your files needed to the `src/assets` - they should be present in a dist build.

Comment: this is how I solved it, added it to src/assets/json directory